# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 three 20-

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, sharekit

I have tried including sharekit to my three 20 project. All share kit files are dragged into  the `Three20Ui.xcodeProject` of three 20.

It shows this error Error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../facebook-three20-726841e 2/src/Three20UI/SHKOAuthSharer.m'

Command `/bin/sh` failed with exit code 1

`SHKOAuthSharer.m`  is a file in share kit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should include sharekit into your main project, and not in one of the three20 projects.

You will have to revert the changes you have made (download three20 again) and try to drag share kit into your Xcode project.

I'm using the ShareKit on a three20 project and it's working fine.

Comment: Is it necessary to download three20 again?Is it possible to delete those files included in three20UI and then drag the sharekit files to XCode project?

Comment: I did as mentioned.
As am doing  #import "SHK.h" in TTPhotoViewController   it shows no such file found error.

Comment: you're not suppose to include the SHK.h header in the three20 project. you should extend TTPhotoViewController and include in your class

Comment: But can you please help on extending TTPhotoviewController